# Write a trigger on Contact and fill its Mailing Address with its Account's Shipping Address

Tags: apex, trigger, update, after-trigger, insert

I am trying to write an trigger for when a contact get inserted or updated its mailing address so i want to copy this mailing address to its associated account's shipping address.

I am getting this error in  my class **Field is not writeable: Account.ShippingAddress**

This is my Trigger-

```java
trigger triggerOnContact on Contact (after insert, after update) {
    if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate){
        CopyAdd .autoCopyAdd(Trigger.New);
    }
}
```

Class:

```java
public class QuesTwentyTwoTrigger {
    public static void autoCopyAdd(List<Contact> conList){
        List<Id> accIds = new List<Id>();
        for(Contact con: conList){
            if(con.AccountId != null){
               accIds.add(con.AccountId);
            }
        }
        List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
        accList = [Select ShippingAddress,ShippingStreet,ShippingCity,ShippingState,ShippingCountry FROM Account Where ID IN: accIds];
        for(Account acc: accList){
            for(Contact con: conList){
                if(con.AccountId == acc.Id){
                    acc.ShippingAddress=con.MailingAddress;
                    acc.ShippingStreet=con.MailingStreet;
                    acc.ShippingCity=con.MailingCity;
                    acc.ShippingState=con.MailingState;
                    acc.ShippingCountry=con.MailingCountry;
                }
            }
        }
        
        update accList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The ShippingAddress field is a compound field, and thus read-only. Use the other fields (Street, City, State, PostalCode, Country) instead. Also, in general, you can use a Map for more efficiency:

```
public class copyAdd{
    public static void autoCopyAdd(List<Contact> conList){
        List<Id> accIds = new List<Id>();
        Map<Id, Account> accounts = new Map<Id, Account>();
        for(Contact con: conList){
            accounts.put(record.AccountId, new Account(Id=con.AccountId));
        }
        accounts.remove(null);
        for(Contact con: conList){
            Account acc = accounts.get(con.AccountId);
            if(acc != null) {
                acc.ShippingStreet=con.MailingStreet;
                acc.ShippingCity=con.MailingCity;
                acc.ShippingState=con.MailingState;
                acc.ShippingCountry=con.MailingCountry;
                acc.ShippingPostalCode=con.MailingPostalCode;
            }
        }
        update accounts.values();
    }
}
```